# How to make one call to API from 2 different components?(Angular)

Tags: angular, rest, api

How can I make one request to API from 2 different components. I attached the code(the html, typescript and the services for these 2 components). How can I make one call to API from these components?. For the this i used rxjs and I created 2 different services. I would appreciate any help.

FIRST COMPONENT

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AgreementsService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

 // Uses http.get() to load data from a single API endpoint
 getBodyService(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  }
}
```

```css
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AgreementsService} from './agreements.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-agreements',
  templateUrl: './agreements.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agreements.component.sass']
})
export class AgreementsComponent implements OnInit {

  public body;

  constructor(private _agreementsService: AgreementsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBody();
  }

  getBody() {
      return this._agreementsService.getBodyService().subscribe(
          data => { this.body = data, console.log(data)},
          err => console.error(err),
          () => console.log('done loading foods')
        )
      }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let b of body">{{b.body}}</li>
</ul>
```

SECOND COMPONENT

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getTitleService() : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    }
}
```

```css
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero',
  templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero.component.sass']
})
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
  public titles;

  constructor(private _heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTitle();
  }

  getTitle() {
      return this._heroService.getTitleService().subscribe(
          data => { this.titles = data, console.log(data)},
          err => console.error(err),
          () => console.log('done loading foods')
        )
      }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let title of titles">{{titles.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is the question? i see two different services here

Comment: you can use same service and try rxjs's `share()` operator. That way it will call the service only once but give output to multiple subscribers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to understand the characteristics/benefits of using Service in Angular

(i) It's a singleton which means it is instantiated only ONCE.

(ii) It is also injectable which means it can be used throughout your application.

Services are used to share data, communicate between components and external data sources

In thise case you are having same code repeated twice in two different services. 
I would recommend you to inject the same service in both components and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two services, just use one. If you want to reduce the number of API calls you can store a local copy of the API response and return that when other components need the data.